# Run create-react-app in a certain browser

Tags: node.js, create-react-app

Is it possible to launch `create-react-app` App in a certain browser of my choice? Currently, it always runs in the Chrome while I want it to do that in the Chrome Canary. Does anybody know?

Comment: What is your system's default browser?

Comment: Chrome, windows 10

Answer (score 18):

You can use `BROWSER` environment variable to set which browser you wanna open the app in. For example,

```
BROWSER=firefox yarn start
```

or

```
BROWSER=firefox npm start
```

will open the app in firefox.

So, you can put something like this in your `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "BROWSER=firefox react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build && sw-precache --config=sw-precache-config.js",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
```

You can read more about it in this [pull request thread](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/1590)

Comment: Is it possible to open Firefox in a given profile? Looking for an equivalent to `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin -p development`.

Comment: Found a way using the script option. See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1533

Comment: But what about exactly Chrome Canary? Did anybody try?

Comment: For Google Chrome, use `"BROWSER='Google Chrome' react-scripts start"`

Comment: With react-scripts 5.x this no longer seems to work.

Answer (score 8):

With current iterations of `create-react-app` this can be accomplished by adding a `.env` file to the project with a "BROWSER" key. It's described in the [Advanced Configuration](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration) section of the documentation.

If you want to use Google Chrome Canary for your development browser (as I do) then you'll need to create that `.env` file in the root of the project with the following contents:

```
# Override default browser for npm start in react-script
BROWSER=Google Chrome Canary
```

Be sure you don't get overzealous and quote it or add a semi-colon at the end. I did both and scratched my head at first why it didn't work.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.env` file with `BROWSER=firefox`

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Set Chrome Canary as default browser in PowerShell (choose the right path first)

   ```
   $chromePath = "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Google\Chrome\Application\"
   $chromeApp = "chrome.exe"
   $chromeCommandArgs = "--make-default-browser"
   & "$chromePath$chromeApp" $chromeCommandArgs
   ```

*(answer from)*
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17536704/11878186

2. Set variable `BROWSER=Chrome` in `.env` file in root directory